# What table/view do you query to get the location name in Oracle apps?

Tags: oracle

I am working on a query that retrieves the item and it's transaction and i am searching for the table that contain the location name , i googled it but all the tables contains the location id

Can anyone help me ?!

Comment: location id for the inventory ? which has the item

Comment: yes , i have the location id but i need the location name

Comment: @besho_talaat `MTL_ITEM_LOCATIONS` table and it's associated views will have the location name and you can try in `MTL_SECONDARY_INVENTORIES_FK_V ` object as well.

Comment: @user75ponic ok , i got it , do you have the ship to location table ?!